# Creating Segments in Amazon Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I am new to Amazon Pinpoint. I have created a sample webapp using AWS  Amplify which generates an event when a button is pressed and sends anaytics to Amazon pinpoint.

Now, I am trying to create Segment for sending email to specific endpoint. But when i am trying to create a segment it shows the following:

[image]

I am new to pinpoint. How can i create a segment and send email when specific event occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating segments, follow the documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/segments-importing.html

When importing a segment, using the CLI or console, type of endpoint and the endpoint address can be specified. If you are trying to send to emails, then channel type should be email and address should be an email address. After importing this segment you will be able to create a campaign with said segment.

For event based triggers, a dynamic segment is needed. This documentation should help in understanding how that works: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/segments-building.html#segments-building-procedure

Using Amplify SDK to create the endpoints, Amplify by default registers endpoints that have OptOut set to all. Need to set OptOut to NONE for any registered endpoint to show up in "Eligible Endpoints" when creating a segment in the console.